# Build a dynamic JSON structure with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

I think I've read all the previous responses to any similar questions without finding an answer.

I am trying to build a JSON structure that looks like this (but much bigger :));

```
[{"APC": {
    "Description": "",
    "Data": "001,044,1064",
    "Units": "",
    "AbbrvUnits": ""
}
}, {"DATE": {
    "Description": "",
    "Data": 1487858497000,
    "Units": "Date",
    "AbbrvUnits": ""
}}]
```

But the closest I can get is this data structure;

```
[{
"DataItem": "APC",
"DataVal": {
    "Description": "",
    "Data": "001,044,1064",
    "Units": "",
    "AbbrvUnits": ""
}
}, {
"DataItem": "DATE",
"DataVal": {
    "Description": "",
    "Data": 1487858497000,
    "Units": "Date",
    "AbbrvUnits": ""}}]
```

with this javascript (node-red):

```
DataVal = {
            'Description' : "",
            'Data' : DataValue,
            'Units' : UnitsStr,
            'AbbrvUnits' : ""
            };
outputJSON.push({'DataItem' : label, DataVal});
```

If I try:

```
outputJSON.push({label : DataVal});
```

I simply get "label" in the resulting structure instead of its value.  Is it possible to get Javascript to expand the variable 'label' and put its value in? There are some examples of declaring 2 data variables to do something like this but they all effectively hard code the 'label' value in the declaration.  However, there are a lot of the 'label' items so I really do not want to hard code it.  It will also make this generic for other similar data I have.

Is this a limitation of Javascript or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
outputJSON.push({'DataItem' : label, DataVal});
```

Should look like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[label] = DataVal;
outputJSON.push(obj);
```

Objects are `key-value` pairs, so, in your original code, you're passing an object that has a key of `DataItem` and a value of the value of `label`, and, because of the way JavaScript now parses object declarations it parses:

```
{DataVal} as {"DataVal":DataVal}
```

**EDIT**

This last part (about how `{DataVal}` is parsed) is as of ECMAScript 2015 (Shorthand Property Names) and more can be read about it under [Object Initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) on MDN

Comment: Brilliant.  It worked; I'll read up more as to exactly why.  Many thanks.

Comment: This does still not quite get me what I am after as I have ended up with too many layers of objects.  To access the data I need to use msg/payload[0].APC (as I have done payload.msg = outputJSON).  Can I structure it so I can simply use payload.msg.APC?

Comment: Ah, Don't use the push as it is unnecessary.  If the items 'label' are unique I can just assign 'obj' to the msg.payload.  Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to tidy this up.  Taking Adam's answer, I ended up with this:

```
Var DataVal ={}
// inside a loop of 'DataItems' assign key:value pairs where
// the DataItem is a unique value

DataVal[DataItem] = {
        'Data' : DataValue,
        'Units' : UnitsStr,
        };
```

I can then assign this to msg.payload in Node-Red. Hope someone finds this and it helps them!